# Function supposed to return valid xml. Returns 'Extra Content' error instead

Tags: php, xml, function, mysqli

I am setting up a web API, which I'm sure can be done more efficiently, but this is v0.1. The first step is visiting `localhost/serverList/api/rest.php?action=allServers&format=xml`. This begins the below chain. I've removed the non relevant parts of the code so that this question is shorter

serverList/api/rest.php

```
<?php
include 'inc/restFunctions.php';
//several lines of code removed. $functionName = allserversxml
if(in_array($action,$possibleActions)){
    if(in_array($format,$possibleFormats)){
        $functionName = $action.$format;
        $result = $functionName();
        header('Content-type: text/xml');
        $return->flush();
    }
}
?>
```

serverList/api/inc/restFunctions.php

```
<?php
function getArrayOfFieldNames($queryResults){
    $fieldList = array();
    while($finfo = $queryResults->fetch_field()){
        $fieldName = $finfo->name;
        array_push($fieldList, $fieldName);
    }
    return $fieldList;
}

function getXMLofQuery($queryResults,$xmlTitle){
    $fieldList = getArrayOfFieldNames($queryResults);
    $xml = new XMLWriter();
    $xml->openURI("php://output");
    $xml->startDocument();
    $xml->setIndent(true);
    $title = $xmlTitle;
    $titlePlural = $xmlTitle."s";
    $xml->startElement($titlePlural);
    $fieldIDName = $title."ID";
        while($row = $queryResults->fetch_assoc()){
            $xml->startElement($title);
                $xml->writeAttribute('id', $row[$fieldIDName]);
                foreach($fieldList as $field){
                        $xml->startElement($field);
                            $xml->writeRaw($row[$field]);
                        $xml->endElement();
                    }
            $xml->endElement();
        }
    $xml->endElement();
    return $xml;
}
function allserversxml(){
    global $link; //from config.php file
    $allServerResults = $link->query("SELECT * FROM servers");
    $xml = getXMLofQuery($allServerResults,"server");
    return $xml;
}
?>
```

The problem is that when I go to the URL, I get the error `error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document. Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.`

Yet...below there is no rendering. What gives?

EDIT: as per ndm's recommendation, I was able to get the error via the source of the page.

```
Call to a member function flush() on a non-object in C:\path\serverList\api\rest.php on line 29
```

So I suppose my question would be then, what is the best way to display xml on a page when it is returned from a function?

Comment: Have a look at the page source, this should show you the actual XML content.

Comment: oh whoa, there's all sorts of data here that isn't displayed! Editing my question to reflect as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the error message and the code, assuming that "*removing non relevant code parts*" does not include removing code from the posted functions and the logic flow, it looks like that the variable you'd want to invoke `flush()` on should be `$result` instead of `$return`.

```
...
$result = $functionName();
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$result->flush(); // like this
```

Comment: oh my goodness. I feel super careless. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, we all know that feel :)